# How i update my react project host on firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a react app project host on firebase. So I am so confused about how I update my project?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following two commands:

```
npm run build
```

and

```
firebase deploy
```

Comment: Thanks, I update it but now my app page shows blank...

Comment: Can you share your firebase.json?

Comment: {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: Please check if your react-app build folder is 'build/'.

Comment: what means 'build/'

Comment: When you build your react app (I mean when you run 'npm run build'), is your app built into a folder named 'build'?